# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306 is when i try to use typeorm in nestjs

Tags: mysql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm, econnrefused

This error when i try to use typeorm in nestjs

i did setting for using typeorm like this

## app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { ApolloDriver, ApolloDriverConfig } from '@nestjs/apollo';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import config from './ormconfig';
import { User } from './user/user.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql', //Database 설정
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: "",
      database: 'hinest',
      entities: [User], // Entity 연결
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      debug: false,
      playground: false,
      autoSchemaFile: 'schema.gpl'
    }),
    UserModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Some People said "You have to start mysql"
so i did "mysql.server start" or "mysql.server restart"
but error still lives..

if you want to see anthor code i can show that

i can not do nothing cuz this erorr

plz help me..

Comment: You might want to read this. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/econnrefused/info  Also, try connecting to MySQL directly with a command like `mysql -u root -p`.

Comment: first of all, thanks your answer i want to know what is means  command like mysql -u root -p? The error lives when i command ``npm run start:dev`` or ``nest start``

i know command like mysql -u root -p can start mysql but it dosen't work for error

Comment: It's hard to help you any further without knowing which OS you use for this. `mysql -u root -p` is a shell command. It doesn't start the mysql server, it uses it, just like your nodejs program tries to use it.

Answer (score 12):

Edit your /etc/hosts and remove the line starting with ::1

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04. Do you mind explaining why it worked?

Comment: If you keep that line, localhost is translated to ::1 (IP6) instead of 127.0.0.1 (IP4). The error occurs because your database is listening on localhost and you try to connect to 127.0.0.1 or the database is listening on 127.0.0.1 and you try to connect to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the host of the connection to `127.0.0.1` as well

```
imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql', //Database 설정
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: "",
      database: 'hinest',
      entities: [User], // Entity 연결
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      debug: false,
      playground: false,
      autoSchemaFile: 'schema.gpl'
    }),
    UserModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])
  ],
```